# How to make selected QTableWidget row bold in pyqt

Tags: pyqt4, qtablewidget

I want to know is it possible to make a stylesheet to make the contents in selected row bold.

i am using `self.tw.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)` to set table to select entire row instead of cell. But i dont want any backgroung color to be changed instead it font should be bold.

How can i achieve this....?

Answer (score 4):

This is a python style code

```
font = QFont()
font.setBold(True)
self.ui.tableWidget.item(row_index, col_index).setFont(font)
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, we would create an onTableEdited() slot, connect it to the itemSelectionChanged() event, and then use table->item(x,y)->setFont() with something like

```
QFont font;
font.setBold(true);
font.setWeight(75);
```

You can also set a QTableWidget to only allow the selection of rows.